# Where does the http.Agent.maxSockets set?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The documentation for [http.Agent.maxSockets](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) states that it is set to 5 by default.

While looking at the source code of node and the modules http, _http_agent, all I can 
see is the maxSockets on agent is set as follows

```
 self.maxSockets = self.options.maxSockets || Agent.defaultMaxSockets;
```

and Agent.defaultMaxSockets is set to Infinity. And I don't see options being passed/set
while creating a new instance of Agent in the http module.

When I do the following, I indeed get the maxSockets as 5

```
var http = require('http')
http.Agent.defaultMaxSockets //5
```

So where exactly is the default 5 being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong version of the source code. If you look at the 0.10.21-release branch you will see the correct assignment in [http.js (l1258)](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21-release/lib/http.js#L1258). Note that `http` has been split into several files on `master` only.

Comment: thanks a ton, do you happen to know any links/resources that point to reasoning behind the change from 5 to Infinity? That seems like a major change.